# Efficient way to use PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter

Tags: php, phpexcel

All code samples I've found in documentation and bundled examples suggest that in order to use the `PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter` interface in PHPExcel you have to start file processing from scratch on every iteration:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
$chunkSize = 2048; 
$chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter(); 
$objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter); 
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) { 
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize); 
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName); // <-------- :-?
}
```

I don't need any fancy processing. I just want to grab data to store it somewhere else. Is there any short-cut I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then don't read the file using a read filter.... this is one option for people with limited memory that need to work with large files, or who only need to read a subset of cells from the spreadsheet.
You're not obliged to use read filters, but can always simply load the whole file if you have sufficient memory.

Another option if you're limited in memory is to use cell caching; or set readDataOnly if you don't need any style information

Comment: Ah, so it basically trades RAM for CPU. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: That's the compromise with a lot of the memory saving techniques unfortunately

Comment: Funnily, my tests show that read filter is actually faster by several orders of magnitude so I'll probably follow that path.

Comment: Read Filter generally isn't slower if it needs to loop a few times for chunking: there's the overhead that it needs to load/parse the file every iteration; but it's only storing a small number of cells in the PHPExcel object each iteration